# Reduce the time-complexity of an algorithm using BellY

Tags: performance-tuning, special-functions

The code below is critical for my computation. I have to evaluate it for `n` around `100` and `200`, unfortunately at approx. `n=75` the computation time increases drastically.

I investigated the problem and found out that this lies in repeated call to the BellY function, which is often evaluated for the same array `implArray@row` but with different arguments.

Is there any way to reduce the complexity of the algorithm? If not, my further idea was to implement the BellY myself and make it remember intermediate results it may produce when called with the same array.

In real code I cache every function, but it accelerates the computation only if called with exactly the same arguments, but if I do `n+1` then it computes all overagain.

````
Module[{implGetCoefficient, implArray, generatePoly, 
  generateCoefficients},
 
 implArray[n_Integer] :=
    Array[2^#*(# + 1)! &, n, 0];
 
 implGetCoefficient[row_Integer, column_Integer] := 
 BellY[row, column, implArray[row]] ;
 
 generateCoefficients[nHarmonic_Integer] :=
    Table[implGetCoefficient[nHarmonic - i, i], {i, 1, nHarmonic}] ;
 
 generatePoly[n_Integer] := Module[{coefficients, powers},
    coefficients = generateCoefficients@n;
    powers = Table[\[FormalC]^i, {i, 0, 2*n - 1, 2}];
    Total@(coefficients*powers)];
 
 (*call site*)
   Module[{n = 20},
     Table[generatePoly@i, {i, 3, n}] // TableForm
   ]
]
```
````

Comment: Interesting problem. It seems you are often calling `BellY` with arguments that should be dealt with by the code logic. For instance, instances like `BellY[n,k,implArray[n]]` when `n<k` will always give 0, no? So you should not need to loop over these cases, but change your loop limits and/or make special rules that intelligently takes care of these.

Comment: Also only the `row - col + 1` first elements of `implArray[row]` are needed in each call to `BellY`. Though I bet the implementation of `BellY` takes care of this, it might introduce some overhead to always pass these long arrays around (for large `n`) when they are not needed.

Comment: Lastly, the coefficients get extremely huge already for `n=50`, do you need them exactly?